# Why does NavigationView have to be a top-level view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to iOS and SwiftUI - why does `NavigationView` even exist? Why isn't there just NavigationLinks whenever we need to link somewhere?

And why does `NavigationView` have to be the top level view? Semantically it just doesn't make sense as the top level View should be `VStack`, `Zstack` etc

Currently:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Do Something")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Do Something")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Both variants work. What's the problem?

Comment: 2nd code block does not work. Only the 1st does

Comment: Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Comment: @Zorgan - don't think of NavigationView as a function. NavigationView is like an area into which NavigationLink destination view renders, and NavigationView handles the back stack. In your second example, "Hello World" would live outside of the area that navigates (i.e. above the back button), which is uncommon for iOS apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI gives you a whole bunch of conveniences practically for free.

One of those is an interface building block called `NavigationView`.

That interface building block has some convenient features and abilities, such as giving you automatic navigation interface (like back buttons to the original View in the navigation bar of the view you followed via a `NavigationLink`, etc).

Most of those conveniences simply wouldn’t make sense if it wasn’t the top level of your view.

Is there something you wanted from `NavigationView` at a lower level? I can’t imagine what, but I suspect there’s another SwiftUI building block that will achieve it, made specifically for the context.